# Troubles with Filtering

Tags: c#

My Filter is problematic. My goal is to have the datagrid on load show any with a created person where  date > Today's day - 1 month. 
I have some filters `surname`, `forename`. I want to Display any `Person` that had some activities within last 3 months. Thats found through this query

```
(ctx.Interactions.Where(z => z.Attendees.Where(w => w.Person_Id == x.Id).Any() && z.ActivityDate >= recent  ).Any())
```

The issue I'm having is when surname or forename is filled, I want the query to ignore the created date prequisite and the Interaction Prerequisite.

```
Items.AddRange(ctx.People.
   Where(x => (
     ((Surname.Length == 0) && (Forename.Length == 0)) ? 
         (x.Created > limit)  : true  &&
         (((Surname.Length  == 0) || x.Surname.StartsWith(Surname)) &&  
         ((Forename.Length == 0) || x.Forename.StartsWith(Forename)) &&
         (ctx.Interactions.Where(z => z.Attendees.Where(w => w.Person_Id == x.Id).Any() && z.ActivityDate >= recent  ).Any())
```

One thing I did try was to move the Interaction query and had it with the x.created but that ruined the runtime. Currently it runs around 15seconds, with that change it takes about 2 mins. Any tips or suggestions would be great.

`recent` is today's date - 3 months

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but try doing `Any(x => ...)` instead of `Where(x => ...).Any()`.

Comment: Another issue could be the use of your conditional operator. You should wrap the conditional expression in `()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the filtering expression:

```
var filteredPeople = ctx.People; // here var should be replaced with IEnumerable<T> where T is the type of items in People
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Surname) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Forename))
    filteredPeople = filteredPeople.Where(x => x.Created > limit);
else
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Surname))
        filteredPeople = filteredPeople.Where(x => x.Surname.StartsWith(Surname));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Forename))
        filteredPeople = filteredPeople.Where(x => x.Forename.StartsWith(Forename));
    filteredPeople = filteredPeople.Where(x => ctx.Interactions.Where(z => z.ActivityDate >= recent)
                                                               .Any(z => z.Attendees.Any(w => w.Person_id == p.Id)));
}
Items.AddRange(filteredPeople);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue may be in the use of your conditional operator. The conditional operator takes the `?` and `:` clauses *completely independently*. So what you're currently telling it is,

```
If Surname and Forename are length 0
  Then return ALL where x.Created > limit
Else
  Then apply all other filters.
```

I've reworked the query a bit. This should improve performance because it will be retrieving fewer (and more accurate) results.

```
Items.AddRange(ctx.People.
   Where(x => (
        ((Surname.Length == 0 && Forename.Length == 0) ? x.Created > limit  : true)  
        &&
         (
            (Surname.Length  == 0 || x.Surname.StartsWith(Surname))
            && (Forename.Length == 0 || x.Forename.StartsWith(Forename)) 
            && (ctx.Interactions.Any(z => z.Attendees.Any(w => w.Person_Id == x.Id) && z.ActivityDate >= recent))
         )
```

Here's another version that doesn't hit the ctx twice, and instead traverses from `Person` > `Attendee` > `Interaction` instead of backwards. This might affect the performance as well:

```
Items.AddRange(ctx.People.
   Where(x => (
        ((Surname.Length == 0 && Forename.Length == 0) ? x.Created > limit  : true)  
        &&
         (
            (Surname.Length  == 0 || x.Surname.StartsWith(Surname))
            && (Forename.Length == 0 || x.Forename.StartsWith(Forename)) 
            && x.Attendees.Any(attendee => attendee.Interactions.Any(interaction => interaction.ActivityDate >= recent))
         )
```